# Is the phrase "put paid to" widely understood outside of the UK?

Tags: idioms, british-english

A comment on [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/339272/166378) notes that the phrase "put paid to" (meaning *put a stop to*) is unlikely to be understood in the US. Another comment indicates that the phrase is widely understood throughout the English-speaking world, but also notes that it is chiefly British.

This leaves me a little confused as to whether I should expect this phrase to be understood outside of the UK. Is this phrase widely understood in English-speaking places like Australia, Canada, Ireland, New Zealand, etc?

(A comment asked me to define "widely understood". Admittedly, any definition will be subjective/arbitrary, but I'm thinking something along the lines of ">=70% of speakers know what the phrase means" would constitute "widely understood" for a given locale)

Comment: I'm in the US, and I don't know what it means.

Comment: [Chiefly British](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put%20paid%20to). Whether it's familiar beyond there will probably depend on how familiar the person is with British culture, media, etc - it's hard to generalise.

Comment: It's [more common in BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=which+put+paid+to%3Aeng_us_2019%2Cwhich+put+paid+to%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3), but it's clearly being taken up in AmE as well, these days. But what's the point of everyone saying whether they recognize the usage or not? Define "widely understood".

Comment: If I'm speaking or writing for an international audience, I want to make sure I am using language that will be understood by all/most of my audience, and I want to avoid phrases that will only be understood by a segment of my audience

Comment: Rule of thumb: Do not use idioms, slang or multi-word phrases (i.e *phrasal verbs*) if your audience first language is not English.

Comment: I've heard it from time to time here in Australia, but wouldn't say it's used commonly. The first time I heard it I understood the meaning from the context.

Comment: It is present in McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. ***put paid to something*** 
*to consider something closed or completed; to mark or indicate that something is no longer important or pending. (As if one were stamping a bill "paid".)* At last, we were able to put paid to the matter of who is to manage the accounts.

Comment: and also in The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer. ***Put paid to*** :Finish off, end, as in We'd best put paid to this issue. [Early 1900s]

Comment: I'm of British decent and have been familiar with it since I was ten or so, but I don't remember ever having heard it used in conversation in the US in the past 50 years. I know I've used it a few times, I just can't remember ever hearing it. It tends to be used with respect to hopes, dreams, and plans.

Comment: To me, “put paid to” isn’t quite the same as “put a stop to”, as the latter suggests taking action to end something rather than an observation that it has ended.

Comment: Yes, *put paid to* is often used where the result in focus is the incidental consequence of a larger action. The accident, and the two pounds of titanium plates used to put his legs back together, put paid to his plans the join the Marines.

Answer (score 2):

“Put paid to” is a metaphor that depends on knowing about marking a bill as PAID by grabbing a rubber stamp, inking it (unless it has its own ink supply), and stamping the bill, usually in red.

A speaker may recognize the meaning of the phrase without that knowledge, but as the era of paper bills and inked stamps fades, the meaning depends on vocabulary knowledge rather than metaphor. Instead of wondering about its use, perhaps the question is whether an audience today would grasp the metaphor.

Comment: You don't need to know the origin of an expression to be able to recognise its meaning, or to use it. It helps but there are hundreds of idioms whose origins are lost in time.

Comment: This is a very helpful explanation, but it makes it more puzzling why the phrase would be a part of British English, and relatively unfamiliar in the United States, given that the rubber stamps of this kind were once widely used there as well.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of sources deem it as British; for instance, it appears on [this](https://lisamende.com/2013/09/the-very-best-of-british-slang-guide.html) list of Britishisms. I don't know if the typical American or non-Englishperson would understand it.

A search for `put paid` in the *Corpus of Contemporary American English* only returns a little over 50 results for its use in print over the past 30 years. Here are two of their examples:

> *2015, National Review: Stick It To ’Em*:
>
> > WAR IS NOT THE ANSWER. But sometimes it is, noted Bill Buckley. For instance, war **put paid** to the nazis and the Japanese fascists.
>
> *2011, Never a Gentleman* by Eileen Dryer:
>
> > Diccan flinched from the thought. He tried one last time to believe that Grace Fairchild had orchestrated her own runaway marriage. One look at the high color on her ashen cheeks **put paid** to that. She was, just as he'd suspected, a pawn.

By contrast, the common alternative for *put paid to* is *put a stop to*, which returns over 1,000 results in a corpora search.

So it *is* sometimes used outside of America, it *is* sometimes used by American writers, but it remains associated with British English. I can't speak to whether it's used in Australia/NZ, but I doubt that >70% of people outside of the UK would understand it.

Comment: You seem to suggest that "a little over 50 results for its use in print over the past 30 years" is a significant amount ("it is used by American writers"), but I think that that level of use is trivial and can probably largely be attributed to other factors. (For example, the author of the Daily Beast article, Stephanie Theobald, is actually British.) It would be more useful if, for example, you compared use of "put paid to" to "put a stop to" so we could get some context.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan - updated. I agree that it's trivial, though I guess I didn't make that clear in the original version. Thanks for your suggestion to do a comparison.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I think this is a better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I am a multi-published author in the US who lived in the UK for 3 years growing up. No one I know here ever uses the phrase put paid, and I only read it in the British online newspaper I subscribe to.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).